# How to apply OLS to binary classification?

Tags: regression, classification

I was asked to use "linear regression" for a binary classification dataset during an interview, and I could not figure out what the interviewer wanted. The task was to predict people's IQ, and the response is $1$ if a person's IQ is above 100, and $0$ otherwise. There were many independent variables, but I was asked to specifically look at a single variable (let's call it $x$), "age", which is represented as an integer from about $20$ to $60$.

Because it's a binary response (and in my case, non-separable), there was no linear relationship between $x$ and $y$, so I was asked what I would have to do in this situation to use linear regression, and how I can use linear regression to model this type of nonlinearity.

My initial thought was you can perhaps apply a nonlinear transformation to $x$ (I saw that $x$ was right skewed, so I thought maybe a log transform would work), and then fit $y$ to the transformed $x$, but that wasn't the answer, and in retrospect, I don't think that makes much sense because the issue here is for each distinct age, there were some responses with a value of $1$ and some responses with a value of $0$, i.e., non-separability.

My next inclination was maybe instead of fitting age directly to the response, we group people in terms of their age, and for each age group, we find the proportion of people with an IQ over 100, and fit age group vs proportion instead, and then do some post processing afterwards. I'm not sure if this was the answer or not.

Is there some obvious way to apply linear regression to binary classification?

Edit: Terminology might be a bit confusing here, and it was also confusing during my interview. When the interviewer said "linear regression," I'm 95%+ sure they implied "OLS" instead of GLM. So let's restrict this question to "How can you use OLS to model a binary outcome."

Also, here's a picture below. The left figure is a simplified version of what the relationship looked like when I plotted $y$ vs $x$. If it looked like the right figure, I think I could've just applied OLS regularly and then straightforwardly truncate the response of OLS to be $1$ or $0$, but I don't see how you can do that with the relationship on the left. It's not separable.

[image]

Comment: I don't think it's obvious, but logistic regression fits the bill.  It is, literally, "linear regression" because it models the expectation of the response as a linear function of the explanatory variable(s).  Are you perhaps wishing to limit the scope of "linear regression" to "ordinary least squares" regression?

Comment: @whuber That's part of my confusion. Normally, I would've just said "let me try logistic regression," but at the beginning of the interview I asked if they wanted me to use "linear regression" or "logistic regression" and the interviewer said "most people use linear regression, so let's try that." It seemed like they were distinguishing between "linear regression" and "logistic regression" even though logistic regression belongs to GLM. I think they were strictly implying that I should try OLS.

Comment: Your figure on the left does not appear separable using logistic regression (or much of anything else), either.

Comment: @Dave Right. When I initially asked if I should use logistic regression or linear regression, that was before we did any plotting, so I didn't know it looked like the left plot. Maybe this was a trick question and the answer was "You can't."

Comment: If your interviewers say that "most people use linear regression", that may be right, but it doesn't change that it's the wrong tool. Either your interviewer is statistically illiterate (nothing wrong with that, as long as they are open to learning), or they were gauging your reaction to being told to use a hammer to pound a screw into the wall. Are you sure it was not the second kind of situation?

Comment: @StephanKolassa I don't think so. I can't remember how they worded it, but I'm pretty sure they wanted OLS. I also know that, historically, that particular interview round is focused on OLS and its variants like Lasso/Ridge, but I think datasets in the past were more straightforward applications of OLS.

Comment: Of course you can apply OLS in the "nonseparable" case!  It just will estimate a near-zero slope.  A good interviewer will be looking for your concerns about this and your discussion of its reliability, of the OLS assumptions that are violated, and so on.

Comment: Honestly, excluding logistic regression, but allowing regularization like the lasso or the ridge does not sound like they knew what they were doing. Well, as @whuber says, of course you can apply OLS to this kind of situation - just like, as I like to put it, you can indeed pound a screw into the wall using a hammer instead of a screwdriver. If I was hiring a carpenter and asked him to demonstrate how to get a screw into the wall using a hammer (no screwdriver), I wonder how the candidate would take this...

Comment: @whuber After I plotted the relationship, I did mention that if we just applied OLS, I'm pretty sure the curve would end up something close to $ y \approx C$, where $C \in [0, 1]$, and they were like "right, so how would you model the nonlinearity?"

Comment: Not sure what the interviewer meant, but one thing you can try is to bucketize (and maybe normalized) the age. The you have several categorical features which you can learn weight for each using OLS. This should output the probability for having IQ > 100 for each bucket.

Comment: @ofer-a I think this is what I was getting at in my OP and during the interview, where for each distinct age, we find the proportion of people with IQ over 100, and fit this proportion to each age group.

Comment: Even if you do bin the ages (problematic) or use some kind of nonlinear model like splines (Frank Harrell's suggestion), there does not appear to be any relationship between age and the outcome category.

Comment: you only need to discretise the age to do @ofer-a suggestion, OLS will "find the proportion of people".
Precisely because its non separable I would guess OLS would actually work (even without nonlinear transformations) eg perhaps IQ vs age goes from 48% (at 20) to 52%  (at 60, or vice versa), and slight change in probabilities is perfectly well modelled by linear relationship.

Comment: This question begins to sound like an exercise in futility.  It's kind of like being asked "how would you go about preparing a spaghetti dinner using only an axe?"